# A filter for a search input in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to make a filter for a Search Input with React.
I have a `fournisseurs` array with an object inside, like this:

```
fournisseurs: [
    {
      'id'              : '0',
      'codeFournisseur' : '2222222',
      'categorie'       : 'sdfgsdfg',
      'statusJuridique' : 'sdfgdfhs',
      'raisonSociale'   : 'sdfhdhs',
      'typeReglement'   : 'sdhgdfhdf',
      'delaiReglement'  : 'sdhfgdhs',
      'franco'          : 'sdfhsdh',
      'fraisDePort'     : 'sdhhsdhf',
      'adresse'         : 'sdfhsdfh',
      'codePostal'      : 'sfdgsdfgsdfg',
      'ville'           : 'sdgsd',
      'pays'            : 'France',
      'telephone'       : '+333333333333',
      'mail'            : 'dfxgdf@sdhgdfh.fr',
      'siteInternet'    : 'http://www.sdfgsdfhs.fr',
      'tvaIntracomm'    : 'sdfhsdghsdgh'
    }
]
```

The problem is that I can't make a search on the whole object.
I can only search on one element (raisonSociale here) of the object such as:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setData(searchText.length === 0 ? fournisseurs : _.filter(fournisseurs, fournisseur => fournisseur.raisonSociale.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())))
    }, [fournisseurs, searchText]);
```

Would someone guide me if it would be possible to use a spread operator in the filter method or something similar to retrieve all elements of the object from the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have added two new keys which you can also search

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData(searchText.length === 0 ? fournisseurs : {
       _.filter(fournisseurs, fournisseur => 
         return fournisseur.raisonSociale.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                fournisseur.typeReglement.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                fournisseur.delaiReglement.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
      )
    })
}, [fournisseurs, searchText]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had to modify the syntax a little bit, but this way works perfectly.